# Editing files using C

Tags: c, file, unix

Input.txt:

```
File entry structures:
[0] ""  0       -1
[1] ""  0       -1
[2] ""  0       -1
[3] ""  0       -1
[4] ""  0       -1
```

I want to create a new file (output.txt). The C program replaces the first occurrence of "" with "Testfile", so it looks like:

Output.txt:

```
File entry structures:
[0] "Testfile"  0       -1
[1] ""  0       -1
[2] ""  0       -1
[3] ""  0       -1
[4] ""  0       -1
```

My work so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *input_file, *output_file;
    int  size, fblock;
    char index[81];
    char name[81];
    
    
    input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    
    output_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    
    // ignore "File entry structures:" line when reading/writing
    
    while (fscanf(input_file, "%80s %80s %d %d", index, name, &size, &fblock) == 4) {
        fprintf(output_file, ... );
    }
```

I'm lost on what to provide to the second parameter of `fprintf`. My goal is to write it in the same way as it was in the input file.

Comment: You should more be worried about your paramters to `fscanf`. Does your compiler complain about type mismatch for 4th format specifier? Why do you pass `&size` but `fblock`? And you provide 4 format specifiers but expect `fscanf` to return `2`. That does not match

Comment: For `fprintf` you can simply use `"%s %s %d %d\n"` as format string but your code is missing the logic for replacing the string.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry about that. It is fixed now

Comment: A couple of references: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf    
https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Learn to read and understand those kinds of references and things will be a lot easier.

Comment: Depending on what alignment of your numbers you want to achieve, you might add field width modifiers or just some spaces into the format string. Or is your goal to write it in the same way as it was in the input file? In that case you cannot use `fscanf` as that does not provide any information about the whitespaces.

Comment: You should connect with [your classmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625260/writing-to-unix-files-using-c) and work on the assignment together.

Comment: @Gerhardh Should I use `fgets` instead?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. Do you need to preserve spacing or not?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, my goal is to write it in the same way as it was in the input file

Comment: Then yes, use `fgets` and search `"\"\""` in the string.

Comment: @Gerhardh Why should I search for `"\"\""` ?

Comment: Because that is `""` you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There probably are a lot of ways to solve this, so here is a suggested way to do this for your review.  In your program, I added in some string checking and manipulation to produce the desired outcome of having the literal "Testfile" associated with the first record of your data.  Following is a revised version of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input_file, *output_file;
    int  size, fblock, i;
    char index[81];
    char name[81];
    char h1[12], h2[12], h3[12]; /* Some work variables to bring across the heading for line #1 in the output file */
    
    input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    
    output_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    
    // Ignore "File entry structures:" line when reading/writing
    
    i = fscanf(input_file, "%s %s %s", h1, h2, h3); /* The header line has three strings/words */
    
    fprintf(output_file, "%s %s %s\n", h1, h2, h3);  /* In the example the first line of the output file has this heading */
    
    while (1)
    {
        i = fscanf(input_file, "%80s %80s %d %d", index, name, &size, &fblock);
    
        if (i == -1) break;
        
        if (i == 4)
        {
            if (strcmp(index, "[0]") == 0)
            {
                strcpy(name, "\"Testfile\""); /* Replaces the null value with the literal */
            }
            fprintf(output_file, "%s %s %d %d\n", index, name, size, fblock);
        }
    }

   fclose(input_file);
   fclose(output_file);

   return 0;
}
```

I completed the formatting for the "fprintf" function for your review.  Also, the "strcmp" and "strcpy" functions from "<string.h>" were used to provide the search/replace for "Record [0]".

When I ran this program using your sample data, here is how the data in the output file appeared.

```
File entry structures:
[0] "Testfile" 0 -1
[1] "" 0 -1
[2] "" 0 -1
[3] "" 0 -1
[4] "" 0 -1
```

As I noted, there are probably other ways to get to the results you want, but this should provide a starting point for you.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: This helped a lot! The files are actually unix files (binary). How would the code change to accommodate unix files?

Comment: Unix and Linux can have and use text files, but if your files truly are binary files, you would then want to add a "b" to the file type parameter when you open it (e.g. fopen("filename", "rb")).

Comment: I change it to `rb` and `wb` respectively, but I get `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated`

Comment: Does it happen if you leave the file open parameters as "r" and "w" respectively?  Also, are you now loading data that has large strings (possibly larger than the defined character size)?  Possibly, you have exceeded the the memory allocation for the string.  I did a quick test where one of the records had an exceedingly long string and I got that message regardless of it being treated as a text file or a binary file.

Comment: `if (i == -1) break;` If you mean `EOF` you really should use `EOF` and not `-1`. Also it might be worth checking for values `0-3` in case not all values were found.

Comment: `if (strcmp(index, "[0]") == 0)` What is supposed to happen if the first `""` occurs in another line? Also, how does this code preserve spacing?

Comment: @Heskinammo if you are really dealing with binary files, you should not use string functions. If one of your strings you read via `fscanf` holds some 0 byte, your program will break. The content you show is clearly text. Where does the need for binary files come from? Maybe just a misunderstanding, but Unix Files are not necessarily binary files.

Comment: @Gerhardh its actually stored in just `output` not `output.txt`: ` output_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");` I used txt as a stepping stone. Since it now works for txt files, I was hoping it would also work for binary files.

Comment: @Heskinammo The file name does not matter at all. It is about the content.

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard.  And I am procrastinating too much.  This can be done with a very simple state machine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    int seen = 0;
    FILE *in = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    FILE *out = argc > 2 ? xfopen(argv[2], "r") : stdout;

    while( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF ){
        if( seen == 0 && c == '"' ){
            int d = fgetc(in);
            if( d == '"' ){
                fputs("\"Testfile", out);
                seen = 1;
            } else {
                ungetc(d, in);
            }
        }
        fputc(c, out);
    }
    return 0;
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}
```